# Query on how to study well in non-Euclidean/ hyperbolic geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I m currently taking a course on non-Euclidean/ hyperbolic geometry, mainly consists of using axioms in these geometries, etc... to proof certain theorems or results.

I am a beginner in these sorts of "non-regular" geometries, and had a hard time of proving things by using only axioms as mentioned above and not theorems from Euclidean geometry, and some of the results in non-Euclidean geometry seems so wield(i.e. Lambert quadrilaterals) as they are different from the Euclidean geometry that I had knew and adapted to from the past.

So now I can only do the proofs very slowly (like finish a few questions in days but not hours) and sometimes can't finish the proof. Plus I don't have much exercise questions to practice on.

Therefore, I did poorly so far in this subject, I want to improve but I can't think of ways for improving.

Are there any suggestions or books/websites/etc... recommendation so that I can understand more clearly in the subject and do proofs faster?  Thank you!

Comment: http://www.wildegg.com/youtube-universal-hyperbolic-geometry.html,  
http://www.pavleck.net/bookinfo/an-introduction-to-non-euclidean-geometry.pdf/, https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~cheritat/GalIII/galery.html

Comment: Thank you so much!